# Initialize arrays using ternary operator

Tags: java, arrays, ternary-operator

i tried something like this:

```
boolean funkyBoolean = true;
int array[] = funkyBoolean ? {1,2,3} : {4,5,6};
```

But this code won't even compile.
Is there any explanation for this? isn't  `funkyBoolean ? {1,2,3} : {4,5,6}`  a valid expression?
thank's in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can only use the `{1, 2, 3}` syntax in very limited situations, and this isn't one of them.  Try this:

```
int array[] = funkyBoolean ? new int[]{1,2,3} : new int[]{4,5,6};
```

By the way, good Java style is to write the declaration as:

```
int[] array = ...
```

EDIT: For the record, the reason that `{1, 2, 3}` is so restricted is that its type is ambiguous.  In theory it could be an array of integers, longs, floats, etc.  Besides, the Java grammar as defined by the JLS forbids it, so that is that.

Comment: In JDK7 it looks as if `{1, 2, 3}` (in other situations) will be a set, with type determined by target typing (like generic methods, such as `Arrays.asList`).

Comment: Just for the record, the proposed language change that Tom's comment alludes to did not make it into JDK 7.

Answer (score 6):

```
boolean funkyBoolean = true;
int[] array = funkyBoolean ? new int[]{1,2,3} : new int[]{4,5,6};
```

Answer (score 4):

> An array initializer may be specified
>   in a declaration, or as part of an
>   array creation expression ([§15.10](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#46168)), creating an array and providing some initial values

That's what the [Java Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html#11358) says (10.6). So the 'short' version (with the creation expression) is only allowed in declarations (`int[] a = {1,2,3};`), in all other cases you need a `new int[]{1,2,3}` construct, if you want to use the initializer.