# Java ternary object array creation - style

Tags: java

Which is better?

```
    public Foo[] createObjects(boolean displayAll) {
        return displayAll ? 
                    new Foo[] {new Foo (x, y, z), new Foo(z, y, x) } :
                    new Foo[] {new Foo (x, y, z)} ;
    }
```

OR

```
    public Foo[] createObjects(boolean displayAll) {
        Foo foo = new Foo (x, y, z);
        return displayAll ? 
                    new Foo[] {foo, new Foo(z, y, x) } :
                    new Foo[] {foo} ;
    }
```

and why?

The second way looks clearer to me because it's obvious that whether displayAll is true or false, the first Foo is being created.

This question is NOT a duplicate of :
[Initialize arrays using ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796791/initialize-arrays-using-ternary-operator)
That question asks how to create two completely different arrays based on evaluation of a boolean. My question is how to (or whether to) clearly show that one array being created is a subset of the other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796791/initialize-arrays-using-ternary-operator

Comment: Based on DRY principle your second code is relatively better

Comment: @AshishSrivastava That isn't a duplicate... read the whole question

Comment: @qxz thanks... how do i move it?

Comment: No, this would ***not*** be good on Code Review.  @qxz, please don't suggest such moves until you've understood [their guide for it](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/9874).

Comment: @qxz anycard I doubt it, Code Review is for reviewing *working* pieces of code. At the least this code should be turned into a real working piece of code first. Read [What's on topic on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: There are almost countless number of ways to make code easy to read. In this particular case I want to go against the experienced crowd and say that the first option is better. This since I can see what both return values are returning with one gaze. The second option require two gazes. This will however change if the code gets longer. If the constructor is too messy it will also be complicated. In that case a builder might be useful for clarity (maybe not necessarily performance though). So as already said, this is really an opinion-based issue.

Comment: @qxz I haven't flagged it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how to (or whether to) clearly show that one array being created is a subset of the other.

If you just want to do that, I think the approaches both can show one is a subset of the other.

But the DRY principle states that "Don't Repeat Yourself" so under that principle the second approach would be better.

Don't know if this is just me, I think the second approach can be improved by doing this:

```
public Foo[] createObjects(boolean displayAll) {
    Foo foo = new Foo (x, y, z);
    Foo otherFoo = new Foo(z, y, x);
    return displayAll ? 
                new Foo[] {foo, otherFoo } :
                new Foo[] {foo} ;
}
```

I just like to keep the level of abstraction the same on each line. Also, this clearly shows that if `displayAll` is true, other Foo objects will be returned.

Comment: Of course, if constructing a `Foo` is expensive or has side effects, your suggestion wouldn't be best

Comment: Please don't answer these kinds of opinionated questions.  It gives the impression that these kinds of questions are okay to answer.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with this question. The intent is only to improve one's coding style. Perfectly ok to answer it.